# Define fields in Template via JSlink question

Tags: 2013, jslink

I created the following code in JSlink and connected the file to a site column:

```
Type.registerNamespace('hiddenFiledContext')
var hiddenFiledContext = window.hiddenFiledContext || {};
hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {};
hiddenFiledContext.Templates.OnPostRender = OnPostRenderFunction;

hiddenFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
    'TestColumn': {
        'NewForm': FieldRender,
        'EditForm': FieldRender,
        'DisplayForm': FieldRender
    }
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(hiddenFiledContext);
```

The OnPostRender function is triggered correctly. 
But when I change the defining of the fields to the following example:

```
hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {
Fields: {
    'TestKolom': {
        'NewForm': FieldRender,
        'EditForm': FieldRender,
        'DisplayForm': FieldRender
    }
 }
};
```

The OnPostRender function isn't triggered. What's the reason why the function isn't triggered that way?

I came up with the not working notation because of an example of "Office DEV-PNP": https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Branding.JSLink/Branding.JSLink.NCSS/Style%20Library/OfficeDevPnP/Branding.JSLink/TemplateOverrides/TaxonomyOverrides.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because during the execution of your code, you are slowly building up the `hiddenFieldContext` object.  First, when you create it, it's empty.  Then, you build on it and tell it that it has a property `Templates` that's also empty:

```
hiddenFieldContext.Templates = {};
```

Then you add on to the `Templates` property, and tell it that it has a child property of `OnPostRender`, and `OnPostRender` refers to a function:

```
hiddenFieldContext.Templates.OnPostRender = OnPostRenderFunction;
```

But, as soon as you do

```
hiddenFieldContext.Templates = {
    Fields: { }
}
```

you have effectively "erased" the `OnPostRender` property that you had just added.  You are saying "ok, forget that I just added `OnPostRender` to `Templates`, now `Templates` equals this other object structure".

If you want to structure your code in the way of your second example, you will have to do:

```
hiddenFieldContext.Templates = {
    OnPostRender: OnPostRenderFunction,
    Fields: {
        // your field stuff here
    }
}
```

Here is a good primer on working with Javascript objects:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects